# QODBC SQL timeout

Tags: c++, sql-server, qt, connection-timeout, unixodbc

I have a C++ QT application running on many devices, which needs to communicate to MS SQL server. 
I'm using QODBC3 (unixODBC) driver.

The SQL connection is once initialized and connected and then used repeatedly. Thanks to this, the query runs fast (max 20ms).

Everythink works fine when there is no connection issue. When network connection is lost for even short time, the SQL connection can not "reconnect".

I tried to check if connection is on before each query attempt, but `QSqlDatabase::isOpen()` returns true unless `close()` is called. It does not change after network issue.
In my oppinion, the best way would be setting the timer in ODBC driver to some short time and try to reconnect when timeout goes off. But the timeout in ODBC is set to cca 15 minutes and I was not able to set different value.

```
SQLConnection.setConnectOptions("SQL_ATTR_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT=5");
```

This command seems to change nothing, I even tried to complete nonsense in the string, but with no error or something.

My next try was to ping the server every time before running query, but if the network connection is on again, ping goes true and SQL connection is still broken.

My "temporary" solution is to open SQL connection before each query and close it afterwards (with ping preceding the opening). But this solution prolongs each query to cca 500ms and I am not realy happy about it.

Four possible solutions from my side:

- Succesfully set timeout in ODBC driver
- Implement my own timeout in higher level above QSqlDatabase
- Detect network issues before trying to run SQL query
- Keep the temporary solution and pretend it can not be changed :-(